# counts with 2 variables

Tags: python, bins

In a research study I have 2 variables:

```
x = number objects remembered
y = % tasks completed correctly
```

as follows:

```
x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7])
y = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5,0.75, 1.0,1.0,0.6,0.5,0.75])
```

I would like to return the result of the number of:

```
WMC Percent Count
2   100      3
3    33      2
3    66      2  etc.
```

I note the `scipy.stats.itemfreq` and `np.bincounts` only work for one variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a recent version of numpy (1.9.0 or higher) you can use [unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the `return_counts` flag enabled. That will give you 2 arrays, one with values and one with the counts.

Here's a slightly modified version of the `numpy.unique` method which works for your case:

```
def unique(ar):
    ar = ar[np.lexsort((ar[:, 1], ar[:, 0]))]
    flag = np.concatenate(([True], (ar[1:] != ar[:-1]).any(axis=1)))
    idx = np.concatenate(np.nonzero(flag) + ([ar.size / 2],))
    return np.array(zip(ar[flag][:, 0], ar[flag][:, 1], np.diff(idx)))

print unique(np.array(zip(x, y)))
```

Result:

```
[[ 2.    1.    3.  ]
 [ 3.    0.33  2.  ]
 [ 3.    0.66  2.  ]
 [ 3.    1.    1.  ]
 [ 4.    0.5   1.  ]
 [ 4.    0.75  2.  ]
 [ 4.    1.    3.  ]
 [ 5.    0.4   1.  ]
 [ 5.    0.5   1.  ]
 [ 5.    0.6   1.  ]
 [ 5.    1.    2.  ]
 [ 6.    0.6   1.  ]
 [ 6.    0.75  1.  ]
 [ 6.    1.    2.  ]
 [ 7.    0.5   1.  ]
 [ 7.    0.75  1.  ]]
```

Comment: Thanks Wolph, would you be so kind as to elaborate as when I tried unique I returned a list of counts on y followed by count on x and not on the combined set, xy.

Comment: @Panther33: yeah... by default `unique` tries to flatten the array. That can be fixed with a custom dtype though. I'll add an example :)

Comment: binscount_stack = np.vstack(np.unique(xy[:,1:2], return_counts=True)).T as column 0 = index.

Comment: Excellent Wolph, is it possible to append the second array (counts) to the first (WMC, perc) so that I can use later for my histogram? Also you code misses out some sol'ns see groupby code below

Comment: With a simple zip trick as I did in the code, we can do that. I'm not around a computer right now but I can add an example later.

Comment: @Panther33: I noticed a few errors, they're fixed now with the results merged in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier on in your code why not construct a dictionary linking 'number objects remembered' to '% tasks completed correctly'?

i.e.

```
completed_tasks = {2 : 1.0, 3 : 33, 4 : 66}
```

then, you can easily add the completed tasks count to the array that is returned by `scipy.stats.itemfreq`:

```
a = scipy.stats.itemfreq(x)
a = [i.append(completed_tasks[i[0]]) for i in a]
```

Comment: Thanks John, only trouble that approach is that I don't have a finite completed_tasks as y is an independent variable (maths comps), for example, subject could recall 5 objects but get 1, 2-5/5 tasks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for that purpose:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7])
>>> y = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5,0.75, 1.0,1.0,0.6,0.5,0.75])
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(zip(x,y))
>>> c
Counter({(2, 1.0): 3, (4, 1.0): 3, (3, 0.66000000000000003): 2, (5, 1.0): 2, (3, 0.33000000000000002): 2, (6, 1.0): 2, (4, 0.75): 2, (7, 0.5): 1, (6, 0.59999999999999998): 1, (5, 0.40000000000000002): 1, (5, 0.59999999999999998): 1, (3, 1.0): 1, (7, 0.75): 1, (6, 0.75): 1, (5, 0.5): 1, (4, 0.5): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is suitable in your case, however, you can do this using `itertools.groupby()` on the zipped lists:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7])
y = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5,0.75, 1.0,1.0,0.6,0.5,0.75])

print "WMC\tPercent\tCount"
for key, group in groupby(sorted(zip(x, y))):
    print "{}\t{}\t{}".format(key[0], int(key[1]*100), len(list(group)))
```

**Output**

```
WMC Percent Count
2   100 3
3   33  2
3   66  2
3   100 1
4   100 3
4   75  2
4   50  1
5   100 2
5   60  1
5   40  1
5   50  1
6   75  1
6   100 2
6   60  1
7   50  1
7   75  1
```

**Updated to produce numpy array**

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7])
y = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5,0.75, 1.0,1.0,0.6,0.5,0.75])

results = np.array([(key[0], int(key[1]*100), len(list(group)))
                        for key, group in groupby(sorted(zip(x, y)))])
```

**Output**

```
>>> results
array([[  2, 100,   3],
       [  3,  33,   2],
       [  3,  66,   2],
       [  3, 100,   1],
       [  4,  50,   1],
       [  4,  75,   2],
       [  4, 100,   3],
       [  5,  40,   1],
       [  5,  50,   1],
       [  5,  60,   1],
       [  5, 100,   2],
       [  6,  60,   1],
       [  6,  75,   1],
       [  6, 100,   2],
       [  7,  50,   1],
       [  7,  75,   1]])
```

Comment: How can I use your solution to create an array for later use in my 3D histogram and other analyses?

Comment: @Panther33: I assume that a numpy array would be useful. See updated answer.